# Conditional expectation with a third random variable

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3079460/276181) some basic steps were given as understood, and I've been trying to fill in the gaps without much success. Specifically, the problem calls for random variables $X,$ $Y,$ and $U,$ linked by the formula

$$U = Y - E[Y\vert X]$$

and the exercise calls for demonstrating that $U$ is uncorrelated with $X.$

I am stuck at the first step in the comments to the post:

*Compute $E(U|X)$ and then $E(U).$ Repeat with $E(UX|X).$ What happens?*

The person asking the question quickly comes back with $E(U\vert X)=0.$

I can see that linearity would allow $E[U] = E[Y] - E[E[Y\vert X]]=E[Y]-E[Y]=0,$ but all the searches I have done on conditional expectation entail either summations of PMFs or integrations of PDFs.

> How can I calculate $E(U\vert X)$ and $E(UX\vert X)$ from the information given in the exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute first
$$
E(U|X) = E((Y - E(Y|X))|X) = E(Y|X) - E(E(Y|X)|X) = E(Y|X) - E(Y|X) = 0 
$$
Here I have used linearity of the conditional expectation and the fact that $E(E(Y|X)|X) = E(Y|X)$, i.e. the conditional expectation acts as a projection. *Repeated conditioning does not change anything.*

It follows that $E(U) = E(E(U|X)) = 0$.

Next
$$
E(UX|X) = X \cdot E(U|X) = 0 \,. 
$$
Here the general formula $E(g(X)Y|X) = g(X)E(Y|X)$ was also used. *Terms that depend only on the conditioning r.v.  $X$ may be treated as constants.*

Therefore also $E(UX) = 0$. Consequently $E(UX) = 0 = E(U)E(X)$ and this implies that $U$ and $X$ are uncorrelated.

Comment: Thank you. I follow everything except for the beginning of the last paragraph... Why, "Therefore also $E(UX)=0$?

Comment: It's a way of using the law of iterated expectations: $E\left(E(UX\vert X)\right)=E(UX)=0.$ Same as for  $E\left(E(U\vert X)\right)=E(U)=0.$ And since $\text{Cov}(U,X)=E(UX)-E(U)E(X)=0.$